# smb share not accessable by user

Tags: smb

I cannot access a smb share with "user2" (member of "sambausers" group) that is configured like this:

- shared folder is owned by "user1:sambausers"
- shared folder has chmod "drwsrwsr-x"
- "smb.conf" has the share configured with "valid users = user2"

If I modify "smb.conf" to "valid users = **@sambausers**" it works!?
I don't understand that: "user2" is a member of "sambausers"!?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple: I'm stupid -.-

A problem was that I had not found any logs and I didn't know anything about the cause.
Key was using the *smbclient* command line utility to get an error message of invalid credentials.

One research later I found that passwords are added via *smbpasswd* command.
And I really wasn't aware of how passwords are being stored in "tdbsam" mode.